# Mostrar PDF sin opción de descarga e impresión

Tags: html, pdf

¿Existe alguna forma de embeber un PDF, para evitar que se descargue e imprima?

Hasta el momento solo logré quitar la barra que aparece en Chrome, pero asi como en Explorer, Mozilla o inclusive con click derecho tambien se puede. También con js para quitar clicks pero si permite dentro del PDF, lo cual hace que sea inútil.

Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento. En el head:

```html
<script language="Javascript">
document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false}
</script>
```

Y el pdf en:

```
<object class="s_fondo" border="1" data="http://pagina/PDF/uno.pdf#toolbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="650" height="850" t>
      </object>
```

Comment: No puedes. En cuanto el PDF se haya descargado y abierto en el ordenador del usuario, aunque programáticamente hagas algo para evitar imprimirlo, el usuario podría ir a la caché del navegador, ver el fichero e imprimirlo. Cualquier cosa que hagas en el navegador, evitará que usuarios sin experiencia puedan imprimirlo, pero solo retrasará a un usuario más experto.

Comment: Lo mejor es que agregues contraseña al pdf, y proporcionarla solo a los usuarios que tu desees.

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo; puedes utilizar la etiqueta "embed", te dejo un ejemplo con tu código:

```
<embed src="http://pagina/PDF/uno.pdf#toolbar=0" width="500" height="375">
```

Comment: Lo que hace que la barra no se muestre no es el `embed` sino el `#toolbar=0`.

Comment: Obviamente, con #toolbar= 0 no se muestra y con #toolbar=1 se muestra la barra; la cuestión es que Mario está utilizando la etiqueta "object" en lugar de la etiqueta "embed".