# VISUALIZAR UN REPORTE DE IREPORT EN HTML CON JSP

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans-8.2, ireport

Me gustaria que alguien me indicara cómo visualizar un reporte que realice en ireport en HTML con código JSP de netbeans versión 8.2

Anteriormente yo realice reportes con ireport para generarlos en PDF en JSP con el siguiente código:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer"%>

<%@page import="javax.servlet.ServletResponse"%>
<%@include file="Conexionbd.jsp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        File reportfile = new File (application.getRealPath("inventario.jasper"));
        
        Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter, con);
        
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
        outputstream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        
        
        outputstream.flush();
        outputstream.close();
        
            %>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

El codigo me funciona perfectamente. Ahora quisiera saber que código se utiliza para visualizarlo en HTML.
**He buscado información y es escasa. Agradeceria mucho su gestión.**

Comment: Nos cuentas si esto se parece a lo que buscas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219511/mostrar-pdf-sin-opci%c3%b3n-de-descarga-e-impresi%c3%b3n

Comment: Hola Ruslan, Gracias por tu comentario, pero no es lo que busco. Yo quiero es que el reporte me visualice en HTML y no en PDF. Quisiera saber que codigo se usa en JSP para la visualizar el reporte de realice en ireports en HTML.

Comment: la visualización es la misma una vez renderizado, tal vez lo que quieres es convertirlo a HTML para visualizarlo.

Comment: Exacto eso es lo que quiero. Tu tienes alguna información detallada sobre eso, o me puedo guiar a través del link que me enviaste?

Comment: Tal vez podrías lograrlo medienta pdfbox, pero no le veo mucho sentido ya que es muy fácil meter un pdf dentro de una página web. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268879/convert-pdf-to-html-page-wise-using-pdfbox-library

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, además los reportes que yo tengo en pdf ya me los visualiza en la página web. Sin embargo muchísimas gracias por tu gestion :3